# Brief short circuit effects on long-term reliability of a battery

Tags: batteries, capacitor, lithium-ion, short-circuit, reliability

I have ten 220uF ceramic capacitors across a 3.7V 18650 li-ion battery.
The total 2200uF therefore effectively shorts out the battery for about
a millisecond every time I insert it.

Is this significantly harming the battery every time I insert it?  For
example, will my "number of discharge cycles before capacity falls 20%"
significantly drop if I also remove and insert the battery a few times
every discharge cycle?

I am crudely thinking that there is no harm if the temperature of the battery
never exceeds say 50C, which is easily true here, but that basically ignores the
chemistry.  So, do any 18650 batteries (it seems some might be weaker than others
since they range widely in their DC discharge rates, from 1C to 20C) have some
chemical reliability problem with a brief short-circuit?

Comment: I doubt it; most 1865 cells are rather robust current-wise.  And these are very short pulses.  But will this repeated arcing wear away the terminal contacts?  Might be able to insert a series resistor to limit current, then short a transistor/relay across the resistor after a few milliseconds (so-called precharge resistor.)  This will give the caps time to charge without any huge current spike.